# Using the LNUM Patch to run calculations on int64s in lua

Tags: lua, int64

I am currently working on a Lua project that performs calculations on 64-bit integers. My first instinct was to switch `LUA_NUMBER` to `int64_t` in `luaconf.h`. After that didn't work and some digging around I discovered the **LNUM** patch, which seems to provide the functionality I require.

I rebuilt lua with the LNUM patch by running

> patch < ../../lua512_numbers.patch

After running this and re-running my code, I was still not able to perform math on a number as large as 2^62 + 1. (I was also not able to pass the test.lua that comes with lnum patch).

I switched my luaconf.h in each of the following ways - but it didn't make a difference. _LNUM prints out double.

Note: I've tried this with each of lua 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.5

```
#define LNUM_FLOAT
#define LNUM_INT64


# define LUA_INTEGER    long long
# ifdef _MSC_VER
#  define lua_str2ul    _strtoui64
# else
#  define lua_str2ul    strtoull
# endif
# define LUA_INTEGER_SCAN "%lld"
# define LUA_INTEGER_FMT "%lld"
# define LUA_INTEGER_MAX 0x7fffffffffffffffLL       /* 2^63-1 */
# define LUA_INTEGER_MIN (-LUA_INTEGER_MAX - 1LL)   /* -2^63 */


# define LUA_NUMBER         float
# define LUA_NUMBER_SCAN    "%f"
# define LUA_NUMBER_FMT     "%g"
```

And also tried setting `LUA_NUMBER` and `LUA_INTEGER` to `LNUM_FLOAT` & `LNUM_INT64` directly.

I think I've misunderstood something about the way this patch/lua works & would appreciate any guidance on how to work with either unsigned or signed INT64s.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to use long long as LUA_NUMBER. If you need both doubles and int64, try [my lint64 library](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lint64).

Comment: Thanks @lhf - the library works great. While I'm still curious about why LNUM doesn't do what I want it to do, I'm accomplishing everything I need to so it's all good.